# ansible throwing error when using pip command

Tags: ansible

When I am trying to run pip command through ansible I land up in  error.

> {"changed": false, "msg": "Unable to find any of pip to use.  pip needs to be installed."}

When I debugged on my machine I found pip was installed in latest version. I realized my file uses sudo to run the pip.

So if I do `which pip`
I get the path of pip but if I do `sudo which pip` I get nothing.

I don't know how to change my file so instead of sudo it take

```
- name: "Allow newuser for new super user without SUDO password for using rsync:"
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/sudoers
    state: present
    insertafter: '^%sudo'
    line: "{{ user }} ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/rsync"
- pip:
    name: opencv-python
    state: forcereinstall
    executable: pip
```

I have no idea how to fix this issue

Comment: What does `which pip` return? It sounds like you have it installed in the non-privileged users path, but not a global location

Comment: which pip returns home/newuser/.local/bin/pip

Answer (score 1):

At the remote host find out which pip is used by the remote user. Use the *executable* and *become* the remote user. For example,

```yaml
    - name: Install opencv-python
      become_user: admin
      become: true
      pip:
        name: opencv-python
        state: forcereinstall
        executable: /home/admin/.local/bin/pip
```

See [Becoming an Unprivileged User](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#becoming-an-unprivileged-user). Pipelining should solve the problems of becoming an unprivileged user.

```ini
shell> grep pipe ansible.cfg 
pipelining = true
```

---

Notes

- Whatever you install by pip this way will be available to this particular remote user only.
- Preferably distro packages should be used. For example

```bash
shell> apt-cache search python-opencv
python-opencv - Python bindings for the computer vision library
python-opencv-apps - opencv_apps Robot OS package - Python 2 bindings
```

- See [The pip module isn't always idempotent #28952](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/28952) and the [Conclusions](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/28952#issuecomment-513839216) in particular.

Comment: if i do i am getting this error . fatal: [Atry]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (pip) module: become, become_user Supported parameters include: chdir, editable, executable, extra_args, name, requirements, state, umask, use_mirrors, version, virtualenv, virtualenv_command, virtualenv_python, virtualenv_site_packages"}

Comment: when we say admin is it sudo or local user

Comment: when i tried to use local user instead of admin i start getting permission error i tried to use matolib                  FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": ["/home/newuserr/.local/bin/pip", "install", "-U", "--force-reinstall", "matplotlib"], "msg": "stdout: Collecting matplotlib\n  Using cached https://files pyparsing, setmatplotlib\n ERROR:EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python3/n-35.pyc'\nConsider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.\n\n"}